# Bigquery unnest hits - duplicating values)

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to create a master view of a group in properties that are been  imported into big query but it seem by using the unnest(hits) the SQL is duplicating the data leading to inaccurate values for revenues etc...

I have try to look at understanding why the unnest has caused this but I can't figure it out.

```
SELECT Date, hostname, channelGrouping, sum(transactionRevenue) as Revenue, sum(Shipping) as Shipping, sum(visits) as Sessions, sum(bounces) as Bounces, sum(transactions) as Transactions
    FROM
        (SELECT Date, h.page.hostname as hostname, channelGrouping, totals.transactionRevenue, totals.visits, h.transaction.transactionShipping as shipping, totals.bounces, totals.transactions
        FROM `xxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170401' AND '20170509'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date, h.page.hostname as hostname, channelGrouping, totals.transactionRevenue, totals.visits, h.transaction.transactionShipping as shipping, totals.bounces, totals.transactions
        FROM `xxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170401' AND '20170509'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date, h.page.hostname as hostname, channelGrouping, totals.transactionRevenue, totals.visits, h.transaction.transactionShipping as shipping, totals.bounces, totals.transactions
        FROM `102674002.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170401' AND '20170509'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date, h.page.hostname as hostname, channelGrouping, totals.transactionRevenue, totals.visits, h.transaction.transactionShipping as shipping, totals.bounces, totals.transactions
        FROM `xxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170401' AND '20170509'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date, h.page.hostname as hostname, channelGrouping, totals.transactionRevenue, totals.visits, h.transaction.transactionShipping as shipping, totals.bounces, totals.transactions
        FROM `xxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170401' AND '20170509')
    Group By Date, hostname, channelGrouping
    Order by Date
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
SELECT
  date,
  channelGrouping,
  SUM(Revenue) Revenue,
  SUM(Shipping) Shipping,
  SUM(bounces) bounces,
  SUM(transactions) transactions,
  hostname,
  COUNT(date) sessions
FROM(
  SELECT 
    date,
    channelGrouping,
    totals.totaltransactionrevenue / 1e6 Revenue,
    ARRAY((SELECT DISTINCT page.hostname FROM UNNEST(hits) hits WHERE page.hostname IS NOT NULL)) hostnames,
    (SELECT SUM(hits.transaction.transactionshipping) / 1e6 FROM UNNEST(hits) hits) Shipping,
    totals.bounces bounces,
    totals.transactions transactions
  FROM `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE 1 = 1
  AND ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY((SELECT DISTINCT page.hostname FROM UNNEST(hits) hits WHERE page.hostname IS NOT NULL))) > 0
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170601' AND '20170609'

  UNION ALL
  (...)

),
UNNEST(hostnames) hostname
GROUP BY
  date, channelGrouping, hostname
```

Notice that in this query I avoided applying the `UNNEST` operation in the `hits` field and I do so only inside *subselects*.

In order to understand why this is the case you have to understand how [ga data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) is aggregated into BigQuery. Notice that we basically have 2 types of data: the `session` level data and the `hits` level. Each client visiting your website ends up generating a row into BigQuery, like so:

```
{fullvisitorid: 1, visitid:1, date: '20170601', channelGrouping: "search", hits: [{hitNumber: 1, page: {hostname: "yourserverhostname"}}, {hitNumber: 2, page: {hostname: "yourserverhostname"}}, totals: {totalTransactionRevenue:0, bounces: 0}]
```

If the same customer comes back a day later it generates another row into BQ, something like:

```
{fullvisitorid: 1, visitid:2, date: '20170602', channelGrouping: "search", hits: [{hitNumber: 1, page: {hostname: "yourserverhostname"}}, {hitNumber: 2, page: {hostname: "yourserverhostname"}}, totals: {totalTransactionRevenue:50000000, bounces: 2}]
```

As you can see, fields outside the key `hits` are related to the session level (and therefore each hit, i.e, each interaction the customer has in your website, adds up another entry here). When you apply `UNNEST`, you basically, apply a [cross-join](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#arrays_and_structs) with all values inside of the array to the outer fields.

**And this is where duplication happens!**

Given the past example, if we apply `UNNEST` to the `hits` field, you end up with something like:

```
fullvisitorid    visitid    totals.totalTransactionRevenue    hits.hitNumber
1                1          0                                 1
1                1          0                                 2
1                2          50000000                          1
1                2          50000000                          2
```

Notice that for each hit inside the `hits` field causes the outer fields, such as `totals.totalTransactionRevenue` to be duplicated for each `hitNumber` that happened inside the `hits` ARRAY.

So, if later on, you apply some operation like `SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)` you end up summing this field multiplied by each hit that the customer had in that `visitid`.

What I tend to do is to avoid the (costly depending on the data volume) `UNNEST` operation on the `hits` field and I do so only in subqueries (where the unnesting happens only at the row level which does not duplicate data).

Comment: I was about to post my own response but you beat me to it :) Nice answer! One thing I was trying to figure out from the original question is what the intention of grouping by `hostname` is. It seems like it doesn't make sense to try to associate the sums with it since the hostnames are spread across `hits`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ElliottBrossard :)! I agree about the `hostname`, not sure why OP wants this field. What I've noticed at out website is that for almost 20% of revenue, customers open their sessions  already in cart / checkout pages, so I thought that maybe by grouping by `hostname` one can run some sort of analyzes on this type of traffic (but not sure if that is the true intent of OP as well).

Comment: Thanks for you help, the properties are dealing with mutilpe websites so I wanted there to be easily way to filter in / out hostnames of the websites. Im trying to get some of this data to work with datastudio.